# React next.js Tinymce server side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, next.js

i m using tinymce in my app and i have `/addpost` page in my app where i have tinymce editor. 
 
this page is  static only with some input fields and `tinymce` editor. i think there may be some way to do static rendering with `tinymce`.
currently i m using `@tinymce/tinymce-react` package to render `tinymce` editor in my `next.js` application but it is slow so i want to implemet ssr with it.
How can i implement Server side Rendering with Tinymce in next.js application?
as my understanding since this page content is static we should be able to generate static html at build time and make our app fast. how can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to render on server TinyMCE itself or only the page that contains TinyMCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@tinymce/tinymce-react` is a React wrapper around tinymce, which [initialize it at ComponentDidMount](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-react/blob/master/src/main/ts/components/Editor.tsx#L75), this means that you won't gain any benefit from running ssr on it. SSR will only render an iframe tag at the best case.